# Angular node_modules not recognized for auto import suggestion

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, node-modules, auto-import

I am developing an Angular frontend and have certain libraries that I need to integrate.
After `npm install` the node_modules folder is there with all the needed dependencies that are declared in the package.json.

When I now implement source code and have to access any of the libraries downloaded from the npm registry the auto import suggestions works and the desired import is added.

For all of my own libraries that I received from my own artifacts feed in azure devops, this auto import suggestion does not work in all project directories (f.e. it does work in app.component.ts but not in directory/subdirectory/test.component.ts)

What actually does work is just manually adding the import statement like

```
import { foo } from 'bar';
```

So basically the packages are installed correctly and I can also access them, only this very handy and useful auto import suggestion confusingly does not work.

Any ideas what causes this problem or how I can fix it?

---

FYI:

- I am using Webstorm as IDE but VS Code has the same behavior.
- Angular version 15.0.1
- Node version 18.12.1
- npm version 9.2.0

---

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you generating a declaration file when building your libraries? Do you link the declaration file in the `package.json`?

Comment: I don't generate it explicitly or at least not that I know. I just use ng build to build the libraries. And the integration of those libraries in other projects does work seamlessly. Thus I suppose it can not be caused by the libraries themselves.

Comment: In other words... For full editor support you need to create a declaration file which describes the API of your library, and link this declaration file in your `package.json`.

Comment: I tried out a few things and what stood out was that the auto import suggestion worked in the app.component.ts and app.module.ts, but not in other typescript files. So I guess it has nothing to to with the declaration file @JSONDerulo